# Mounting of /cygdrive/c resolves to C:\cygdrive\c

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am using Cygwin and try to run a bash script which uses the `pwd` command to construct a path and then generate a directory. The problem is that the directory is created under `c:\cygdrive\c` rather than under `c:\` (when I execute `cd /cygdrive/c` I will arrive at `c:\cygdrive\c`. Here are my current mounts:

```
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
E: on /cygdrive/e type vfat (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

Does anybody know what is configured wrongly?

**UPDATE**

Let me try to make it more clear (because all comments mention the script but I am sure the problem is not the script): I do the following on the Windows command prompt:

```
C:\>pwd
/cygdrive/c

C:\>cd /cygdrive/c

C:\cygdrive\c>
```

But actually the `cd` should arrive at `c:\`.

Is it perhaps a problem of the mount order?

Comment: What is your script doing?

Comment: Basically the script is calling ``mkdir`` with ``/cygdrive/c/Users/.../somePath``

Comment: From those few informations, let me think the problem is in your script not related to the mounts. It looks like a mkdir with a relative path instead an absolute. How do you build your variable (if any) to get "/cygdrive/c/Users/.../somePath"? Can you add "set -xv" before your mkdir command and "set +xv" after to see with debug traces? What's the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I have changed my bash script. It first gets the directory in cygwin notation using `pwd` then transforms all `/` into `\` and finally does the following substitution: s/\cygwin\(.)/\1:\/.

Why a `cd /cygwin/c/someDir` when executed from a bash script goes into `c:\cygwin\c\someDir` rather then `c:\someDir` I am still not sure (I understand this behavior when I am doing this in a Windows command prompt, but not within a bash script).